# jQuery Validation Plugin and Codeigniter - form skips validation and submits

Tags: jquery, validation, codeigniter, submit

I'm trying to create validation for my form using jQuery Validation Plugin.
I think I'm doind everything good, but I can't make the form to validate. It always submits without validation. jQuery and jQuery.validate.min are included into the file.
Here's the link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/psQXm3Zr
The code is a bit long.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when an error occurs in the validate options, and `return false;` is then never executed to stop the form submitting.

I can't see anything obviously wrong in your code, but the best way to test is to add the `debug: false` option. This will always prevent the form from being submitted, even if valid. You will then be able to see any javascript errors in the Firebug console.

Comment: I've added debug: true and then it stopped submitting. Then I've looked at the XHR in Firebug and it seems that nothing happened.
But it's showing error inside the plugin file: c.validator.methods[e] is undefined
http://.../js/jquery.validate.min.js
Line 29

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into something similar, but only for date fields. According to [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validator-methods-method-is-undefined), the problem lies in jquery validator 1.7, which is missing dateDE. A few solutions are posted on the thread, but I haven't tried any of the yet.

[Update]
As it turns out the issue with my code was capitalization, not the date fields. I had a field which used minlength and maxlength as rules that followed the date fields, except I capitalized the 'l' in each of their names. This allowed the form to submit even if the date checks failed. Correcting the rules' case fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use method which is undefined - the paste/bin code is not available now, so recheck your methods with documentation or use jQuery.validator.addMethod(...);